# Postgresql Function ignore return statement and goes on to the next return

Tags: postgresql

I was trying to create a postgres function that returns a table, but when i execute the function, the **return** statement it's supposed to close or end the whole function, however it's keep ignoring that ending, and goes on.

The function is quite simple: it just take a validation if the fields are empty. I know that if i put an **ELSE** statement the problem is gonna be solved, however i don't know why it ignore the **RETURN** and im curious to know if there is any way other than an **ELSE** to fix the issue

```
create or replace function fnRegisterUserWin(rUsername text, rFname text, rLname text,rRole text, rBrand text) returns table(id_users int, message text, is_failure_location text, error_fields text[])
  language plpgsql
  as $$
  declare
    sanitazedUsername text;
    sanitazedFirstname text;
    sanitazedLastname text;
    sanitazedRole text;
    sanitazedBrand text;
    errorFields text;
  begin
    sanitazedUsername := str_clean(rUsername,true,true,true,true,true,true,true);
    sanitazedFirstname := str_clean(rFname,true,true,true,true,true,true,true);
    sanitazedLastname := str_clean(rLname,true,true,true,true,true,true,true);
    sanitazedRole := str_clean(rRole,true,true,true,true,true,true,true);
    sanitazedBrand := str_clean(rBrand,true,true,true,true,true,true,true);
    errorFields := '';

    if(empty2null(sanitazedUsername) is null OR empty2null(sanitazedFirstname) is null OR
       empty2null(sanitazedLastname) is null OR empty2null(sanitazedRole) is null OR
       empty2null(sanitazedBrand) is null) then
      if(empty2null(sanitazedUsername) is null) then  errorFields := errorFields || chr(39) || 'Username' || chr(39); end if;
      if(empty2null(sanitazedFirstname) is null) then errorFields := errorFields || ',' || chr(39) || 'Firstname' || chr(39); end if;
      if(empty2null(sanitazedLastname) is null) then errorFields := errorFields || ',' || chr(39) || 'Lastname' || chr(39); end if;
      if(empty2null(sanitazedRole) is null) then errorFields := errorFields || ',' || chr(39) || 'Role' || chr(39); end if;
      if(empty2null(sanitazedBrand) is null) then errorFields := errorFields || ',' || chr(39) || 'Brand' || chr(39); end if;
      return query select  0 as id_users, 'There are required fields that are empty, please complete them and try again. '::text as message,'Empty Fields'::text as is_failure_location,ARRAY[ltrim(',sa,aaa',',')]as errorFields;
    end if;
    return query execute 'select 0 as id_users, ' || chr(39) || 'There are required fields that are empty, please complete them and try again. ' || chr(39) || '::text as message,' || chr(39) || 'Empty Fields' || chr(39) || '::text as is_failure_location,ARRAY[' || ltrim(errorFields,',') ||']as errorFields';
  end;
  $$;

create function empty2null(text_i character varying)
  returns character varying
language plpgsql
as $$
declare
text_p varchar;
begin
if text_i = ''
then text_p := null;
else text_p := text_i;
end if;
return text_p;
end;
$$;

alter function empty2null(varchar)
  owner to postgres;
```

this is the return:

> 0 There are required fields that are empty, please complete them and
>   try again.    Empty Fields    {'Firstname'}
>
> 0 There are required fields that are empty, please complete them and
>   try again.    Empty Fields    {Firstname}

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The two `return query` statements are executed because `return query` does not exit the function. If you want to quit at the end of the `if` block, you can add a `return` statement (alone).

As per the [doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#id-1.8.8.8.3.4.2):

> RETURN QUERY do not actually return from the function — they simply
>   append zero or more rows to the function's result set. Execution then
>   continues with the next statement in the PL/pgSQL function. As
>   successive RETURN NEXT or RETURN QUERY commands are executed, the
>   result set is built up. A final RETURN, which should have no argument,
>   causes control to exit the function (or you can just let control reach
>   the end of the function).

Comment: My god... a final return was the answer. But yep now it work as it should.